# Failure installing pcapy on os x

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, clang, pcap

I'm trying to install pcapy on os x. Here's what happened:

```
Joannas-MacBook-Pro:~ joannaburke$ python/Users/joannaburke/Downloads/pcapy-0.10.8/setup.py install my_init_posix: changing LDSHARED = 'gcc-4.2 -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -g' to 'g++-4.2 -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -g'
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'pcapy' extension
/usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c pcapdumper.cc -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/pcapdumper.o
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'pcapdumper.cc'
clang: error: no input files
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
Joannas-MacBook-Pro:~ joannaburke$
```

I have no idea how to fix this. Google has given me nothing. All help is appreciated. Thanks!

edit: pcapdumper.cc DOES exist, in the pcapy directory.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the pcapy directory and try the command "python setup.py install."  That worked for me.

Comment: setup.py and pcapdumper.cc should be in the same diretory